# Non-instance of class with __iter__

Tags: python, iterator, class-method

Can you override ****iter**** and ****next**** for a class and create an iter without creating an instance?

ex:

```
class MyClass:
  all_the_things = []

  @classmethod
  def load(cls, my_list):
     for item in mylist:
        cls.all_the_things.append(item)

  def __iter__(self):
      self.n = 0
      return self

  def __next__(self):
      result = self.all_the_things[self.n]
      self.n+= 1
      return result


MyClass.load(my_list)
for item in MyClass: print(item)
```

It works if I make an instance
MyClass.load(data)
my_instance = MyClass()
for item in my_instance: print(item)

But when I run it on the Class
for item in MyClass: print(item)
I raise:

```
*** TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Does iterating a class even make sense? I would be hesitant to do this. As a simple workaround though, you could just create your own custom class method, then do `for item in MyClass.get_iterator():` (where `get_iterator` is the method you create). That method could be just `return iter(cls.all_the_things)`, which just delegates responsibility to the list iterator.

Comment: What's the purpose of this question? Is there good reason for the required behavior or it's just an *XY Problem*?

Comment: I have a class that manages some other objects in the all_the_things  list - I dont need to make an instance - just has the data - and I wanted to yield the data to a process without making an instance or needing to know the details of the class

Comment: A class is an instance, so you'd have to implement `__iter__` in the *class of the class*, i.e. the metaclass

Comment: But I really see no reason why you can't just use a class normally and instantiate your class. You *can* use just the class state, but that gives you very little advantage. And if you insist, then I would probably just go with the `MyClass.iterator()` approach mentioned in the comments, I wouldn't use a metaclass just for this.